# JPA annotation @Access

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

**@Access annotation**

i'm confused how this annotation works. I know by default, the access type is defined by the place where we put the identifier annotation (@Id).
If we put it on the field – it will be AccessType.FIELD,
if we put it on the getter – it will be AccessType.PROPERTY.

This is my entity

```
@Entity
public class Student  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long ID;

    private String firstName;

    @Access(value= AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~getFirstName~~~~~~~~~");
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = "FirstName: " + firstName;
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~setFirstName~~~~~~~~~");
    }

    public String getlastName() {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~getlastName~~~~~~~~~");
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = "LastName: "+ lastName;
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~setLastname~~~~~~~~~");
    }
}
```

I add to the Setter prefix ("FirstName: " and "LastName: ") to check if it will be called.

As i have @Id on the field that's means AccessType.FIELD, but i change it in **lastName** to AccessType.PROPERTY.

**As i understood on this case JPA should save to the database firstName field without prefix but lastName with** (because it will call setter *setLastName*)

I'm not sure that i understand how to use this on project and how to check if it works. I want to write a test to prove it but i don't know how to implement this. can you please help me. I want to prove that JPA does not call Getter/Setter to **firstName** and call it for **lastName** fields.

This is my test without implementation

```
class StudentTest {
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "in.memory.test");
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    }
    @AfterEach
    public void destroy() {
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void studentFirstName(){

    }

    @Test
    public void studentLastName(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for exactly - is it a question on when JPA calls your method, if at all, or how to write code to use JPA? Persist a new entity, commit, read it back in a new context, update it, commit - basically do what your app will do and see what calls JPA makes on your entity vs what your application makes.

Comment: The base question is what @Access changing on the Entity and how can prove it on jUnit test

Comment: That is two very different questions. Test is pretty straightforward - run some JPA methods and see what you see. As for what it does: it tells JPA any time it needs to access that value to use the property you've defned. That includes internal access when loading the entity from the DB and even when merging in values from detached instances. If you are just learning how it works, you are better off with a debugger or printing the stack instead of manipulating values or you will get "LastName: LastName: LastName: originalLN" effects. Just printing off where/when it is called should be enough

Answer (score 0):

```
I suppose that you can write something like this:

`
@Test
public void testAccessAnnotation() {
    // Create a new instance of the Student entity
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName("John");
    student.setLastName("Doe");

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(student);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.clear();

    TypedQuery<Student> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.ID = :id", Student.class);
    query.setParameter("id", student.getID());
    student = query.getSingleResult();

    assertEquals("John", student.getFirstName());
    assertEquals("LastName: Doe", student.getLastName());
}

`
```

Comment: Thank you. i'm not sure that i still understand. without Access(value= AccessType.PROPERTY) it would works on that way too because you call student.setFirstName("John") and 
    student.setLastName("Doe");